# GROUP BY with COUNT including rows with 0 count

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning

I need to create query that would show me, how many records has been modified i particular date. The point is, that I would like to include days that has no modifications (and display it as 0) insteed of skipping that row. How to do that?

```
SELECT 
    date as d, count(1) AS `c`
FROM
    `applicant`
WHERE
    (DATE(modifiedDate) >= ADDDATE(modifiedDate,
        INTERVAL - 200 DAY))
        AND (manualModified = 1)
GROUP BY DATE(modifiedDate)
```

output:

```
2013-09-19  40
2013-10-16  74
2013-10-17  104
2013-10-18  186
```

so I need to include 2013-10-17,18 with 0 count as well. Is it possible without making join with temporary table?

Comment: Consider providing proper data set/table definitions @[*Sql Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If the dates do not exist as values in the table, you will have to generate them and left-join  them to your query.